# why sql case condition gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures

I do something like this which works fine :

```
select nameOfCols 
from 
FACost
inner join  FAT as D  on d.nid=a.atypeid  
and
d.nid in (select item from SplitString('1,2,3,',','))
```

But when i use case to handle a situation where user dynamically may enter '' instead of '1,2,3,'. Then it gives error in my case condition

```
declare @selectedAssetTypeID varchar(50)='1,2,3,'
select nameOfCols 
from 
FACost
inner join  FAT as D  on d.nid=a.atypeid  
and
case when @selectedAssetTypeID<>'' then  d.nid in (select item from SplitString( @selectedAssetTypeID,',')) else d.nid=1 end     //error causing lines
```

errors are:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
```

Comment: A `CASE` *expression* has to return a scalar value (per row) of a SQL data type. It cannot return the result of evaluating a predicate since that would be a boolean - and SQL Server doesn't have a boolean data type.

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` and `or` conditions instead of a `case` expression. The `case` expression as you have it is assigning a value (`else d.nid=1`) or checking for a true/false condition (`d.nid in (select item from SplitString( @selectedAssetTypeID,','))`).

```
and (
(@selectedAssetTypeID <>'' and  d.nid in (select item from SplitString( @selectedAssetTypeID,',')) )
or (d.nid=1) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use `in` clause with `case` statement. because `Case` has to return one value per statement (either true or false)

either you can split your queries in two blocks or you can use "`OR`" clause.

```
IF @selectedAssetTypeID = " "
BEGIN
     select nameOfCols 
     from FACost 
     inner join FAT as D  
      on (d.nid = a.atypeid)
     where d.nid = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     select nameOfCols 
     from FACost 
     inner join FAT as D  
      on (d.nid = a.atypeid)
     where d.nid IN
     (select item from SplitString( @selectedAssetTypeID,','))
 END
```

You can also use "`OR`" clause

```
select nameOfCols 
     from FACost 
     inner join FAT as D  
      on (d.nid = a.atypeid)
     where ((@selectedAssetTypeID <>'' and  d.nid in (select item from SplitString(@selectedAssetTypeID,',')))
or (d.nid=1))
```

link for the discussion about the similar issue is below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc8a7a0b-1980-4481-a2df-6a5fde38f362/in-clause-in-case-statement?forum=sqlgetstarted